# At a loss of/for what to do?

Tags: word-usage

I know there is this idiomatic phrase "at a loss for words", but how do you use is for something other than "words"?

> "I was at a loss **for** what to do."

or

> "I was at a loss **of** what to do."

I'm not sure if even either one is correct, though. Can you use "at a loss..." for something other than words?

Also, what is the difference between the sentences below?

> "I'm lost **at** what to do."

and

> "I'm lost **on** what to do."

Comment: Maybe "I'm at a loss **about** what to do" or "I'm at a loss **as to** what to do". The final two sentences you ask about differ only in **at** & **on**: they're both unnatural & not idiomatic English.

Comment: The "as to what to do"? answer seems symptomatic of a tendency that plagues writing today - to load prose with unnecessary prepositions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an area where usage has gradually changed. Historically, the preference was not to use any preposition at all between *at a loss* and *what to do*. But increasingly people now insert one of various alternatives including *as to, for, over, regarding, to know*, etc. And if [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loss%20what%20to,loss%20as%20to%20what%20to,loss%20for%20what%20to,loss%20over%20what%20to,loss%20regarding%20what%20to,loss%20to%20know%20what%20to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is to be believed, the first of those is now the most common form...

[image]

There's no grammatical rule involved here - just idiomatic "custom and practice". Personally, I don't find *any* of OP's suggested **of, at,** or **on** acceptable, but all the alternatives graphed above seem at least "credible" to me (though like most people, I would normally use **as to** in this exact context).

Comment: Do you think that this is acceptable? "I am at a loss as IF to enroll or not". "I am at a loss as WHETHER to enroll or not"

Comment: @E.V.: You can't use ***if*** there. The idiomatic standard is *I am at a loss as **to** whether to enrol or not*. There are actually 9 written instances of [*at a loss as whether*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+a+loss+as+whether%22) in Google Books, but it certainly doesn't sound good to my ear, and you have to compare that to an estimated 1,140 results for [*at a loss as **to** whether*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+a+loss+as+to+whether%22).

Comment: Ok, so I should say ""I am at a loss as to WHETHER to enroll or not". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is similar to "I am at a loss what to do next." In your case, you should say "I was at a loss what to do."

Comment: Oh, so it's actually pretty simple. How about Bill's "I'm at a loss as to what to do"?